# Problema no puedo insertar en java

Tags: java

Creé dos clases una conexion para la BD y otra `Insumo` que tendra un método insertar. Ejecuto el código pero no pasa nada. Creo que es la clase `Conexion` no estoy seguro podrian mirar el codigo a ver cual es el problema

#### Click del botón

```
private void btn_ingresarMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt){                                          
    Insumo obj= new Insumo();
    obj.setUsuario(txtrut.getText());
    obj.setPass(jPasswordField1.getText());
    try {
        obj.insertar();
    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

#### Clase `Conexion`

```
public class Conexion {
    public static Connection con = null;

    public Connection Conectarse(){
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            System.out.println("Registro exitoso");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ropa_trabajo?"
        + "user=root&password=");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString()+"dsgdsh");
        }
        return con;
    }

    public void cerrar() throws SQLException {
        if(con!=null){
            con.close();
        }
    }
}
```

#### La clase `Insumo`.

La clase insumo creo que es donde está el problema

```
public class Insumo extends Conexion {
    private String usuario;
    private String pass;

    public Insumo(){
        super();
        con=super.Conectarse();
    }

    public void insertar() throws SQLException{
        String sql="INSERT INTO usuario(4,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement sentencia=super.Conectarse().prepareStatement(sql);
        sentencia.setString(1,getUsuario());
        sentencia.setString(2,getPass());
        sentencia.executeUpdate();
        super.cerrar();
    }

    /**
     * @return the usuario
     */
    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    /**
     * @param usuario the usuario to set
     */
    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    /**
     * @return the pass
     */
    public String getPass() {
        return pass;
    }

    /**
     * @param pass the pass to set
     */
    public void setPass(String pass) {
        this.pass = pass;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la clase Conexion tu variable Connection con, la tienes como static, allí estás mezclando dos conceptos las variables estáticas no pueden ser accedidas desde métodos que no son estáticas.b Quita la declaración de la variable que tienes dentro del `try` en el método `Conectarse`, ya que está ocultando la variable global.

En el método insertar te vuelves a conectar, no es necesario sólo conéctate una vez y luego consultas la variable y te desconectas cuando lo necesites o termines. Digo que te conectas doble porque lo haces en el constructor y luego en el método insertar de la clase Insumo.

Por otra parte a modo de recomendación en la clase insumo cuando llamas al método de la clase padre usas super, no es necesario hacerlo porque automáticamente tienes Acceso cuando heredas, siempre y cuando sea pública o protegida.

Comment: cambie lo de la variable pero no funciono

Comment: me aparece este error

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: en linea 29                                                                                    PreparedStatement sentencia=Conectarse().prepareStatement(sql);

Comment: imprimi el metodo conectarse de la clase conexion e imprime null

Comment: Verifica en el método Conectarse que en efecto se esté conectando, y que tengas bien configurado el jdbc de Java MySQL porque al no hacerlo correctamente puedes estar retornando un valor nulo

Comment: Cuando llames al método Conectarse en vez de retornar asignalo a la variable con de una vez, y que no sea estática. Luego para hacer los queries usan con.PreparedStatement... y después cierras la conexión.

Comment: ejecute y probe el metodo fuera de la clase y me devuelve la conexion

Comment: hice lo que me dijiste pero igual aparece nula la conexion

Comment: Mira ya vi en el bloque try de Conectarse estar re-declarando la variable. Declara solo la variable en la parte donde la tenías estática y claro quita la parte estática déjala protected o public.

Comment: si hay funciono pero ahora tengo problema de sintaxis en el sql xd

Comment: hay lo arregle . gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Si mal no recuerdo en MySQL debes especificar el esquema, y es muy sensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas en cuanto a nombre de tablas se refiere.

Comment: me faltaba el values en el sql